How to extract the Tls certificate over the https protocol on the Vector by Datadog project?
I'm beginner in rust and i have an issue. I am looking to extract the Tls certificate at the source level in the Https protocol in Vector, I tried to retrieve it via RootCertStore. I am having trouble doing something
Here is what I added in src/sources/util/http/prelude.rs
let roots = rustls::RootCertStore::empty();
for cert in rustls_native_certs::load_native_certs().expect("could not load platform certs") {
            roots.add(cert).unwrap();
        }

println!("{:?}=========>", roots);

And this is the error
enter image description here
It doesn't have the right typing, anyone know how to extract the Tls certificate?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
